# Offline maps on IPhone

Tags: iphone, geolocation, offline

I'm looking for offline maps for IPhone.

For now I've discovered Route-me and CloudMade.

CloudMade doesn't have build in functionality for offline maps. There is an option to setup CloudMade to work offline but other question how to get a map you need.

Route-me works with MbTiles format. There is option to download osm file(From OpenStreetmap) and convert it to MbTiles file.

My questions: Are there sdk for IPhone that support offline maps? And how to get maps suitable for this sdk?

Comment: Offline map service on ANY phone would be a huge plus!

Comment: I didn't found appropriate solution year ago. Now I suggest to take a look at [Route-me](https://github.com/route-me/route-me)

Answer (score 1):

[MapsWithMe](http://www.mapswithme.com) is going to launch an offline maps API for iPhone in late Q1 or Q2 2012.

Answer (score 0):

This app solves what you're looking for: http://www.maptiler.com/how-to/ios/