# Offline map with routing on iOS

Tags: ios, dictionary, routes, gis, offline

Anybody know good solution for offline routing on iOS?
I read some posts but no solution. I know that ArcGis can do it, but they have an expensive plan.
Another good idea, we have an offline map and when we need routing we will go to internet.
But it should be the same map. If anybody know how to do this tell me please.

[Offline Map With Routing - iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12908840/offline-map-with-routing-ios)
[Offline iPhone Map with offline routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12525573/offline-iphone-map-with-offline-routing)
[Offline maps with routing for a particular place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16411770/offline-maps-with-routing-for-a-particular-place)
[Offline maps on IPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9055123/offline-maps-on-iphone)

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, Graphhopper is the best choice for offline routing. The project is quite active, relies on OSM data, can be embedded or consumed as a service sharing the same core logic.
I have successfully integrated it in a few projects (mostly foot routing in indoor/urban areas).

Depending on your needs, you might have to adapt a few lines of Java code.

About your second subject, think of map and routing as two different features, even if a few SDK provide both.

You can rely on graphhopper to compute an itinerary then represent it on a [Arcgis's AGSMapView](https://developers.arcgis.com/ios/api-reference/interface_a_g_s_map_view.html).

https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper-ios

Answer (score 0):

See http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Frameworks and http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing. The entries for some of the frameworks specify whether they can do off-line routing. These wiki pages refer to systems which use OpenStreetMap data, but some of the frameworks can handle other data (e.g., ESRI shapefiles) as well.

Disclosure: I am the author of one of the mapping SDKs mentioned.